# Network issue in React-Native application

Tags: react-native, networking

I have developed an app using React-Native and I put that to Google Store also. But still there is an issue for some devices. Some devices cannot connect to the server while other devices are working fine.

I have generated multiple APKs and uploaded to the store. Still the issue exists. I have put the code in android/app/build.gradle and I wonder all the device types are included. And should I generate the Universal APK too?

```
splits {
    abi {
    reset()
    enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
    universalApk false
    include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is server https or http?

Comment: It's and http server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native fetch() not working android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079383/react-native-fetch-not-working-android)

Comment: The thing is, it works fine in some devices and few devices only has this issue...

Comment: check the operating system, this may affect a newer android version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really recommend to purchase certificate, even if it's free one, but for now you can change your AndroidManifest like this:

```
<manifest 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"> 
    ... 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have all these except those attribute in `<application ></application>`. Hope adding it will fix the issue.

Comment: @KaviduAloka, you are welcome. Accept as an answer, if it really helps.

Comment: Ofcourse I will. But can I check if it's solved and the accept? Please?

Comment: @KaviduAloka, sure. That's what I meant :)

Comment: I did put the update to the store. I'll let you know once it's being published