# Internet is not connected in Android Emulator, when net is taken via mobile through hot spot

Tags: android-emulator, nativescript

I am working in a native-script application, so I use Android Emulator for checking, I have mentioned below the version of Emulator.

The Internet is not connected in my emulator even signal of the WIFI also shows cross mark whenever I connect the internet connection from my mobile (Android Lenovo P2) through hot-spot.

The *emphasized text*Internet does connect in my Emulator whenever I connect internet via my ACT connection wifi through the router.

**Emulator APK version: 26.
Emulator device: Nexus 5.**

Note: My laptop connects the internet only problem in Emulator

Does anybody help me To do any setting has to be done in my Emulator to connect the internet when I connect through my mobile hot-spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by adding this line in Androidmanifest.xml 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Answer (score 3):

This clearly indicates Android emulator doesn't recognize youe mobile network connected with your machine network configuration. I would recommend to try following actions to resolve this issue.

1. Open the AVD Manager and wipe the data of that emulator.
2. If you were working with wifi network and instantly switch with your mobile data may cause this problem. just try to restart the emulator and try.
3. Your Emulator may be pointed with older version of SDK, so you may want to uninstall Android Emulator and re-install it. Sometimes older SDK data causes the issue that you have encountered.
4. Reboot your machine then connect freshly with your mobile data started with emulator and check it out.
5. If above nothing works just uninstall AVD and re-install.

Look out this [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet) as well.

Please let me know the above solutions works for you! Cheers!!!

Comment: Sathish, Thanks for your reply. I have fixed that added below line in manifesto file in android 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: hmm.. I thought your app has been already running and instantly you are facing this issue. anyway this should be basic solution. Thanks!