# NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I Implemented code for download Expansion file from play store, My file in getting download but in between downloading .OBB file I am getting below Error

```
NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
```

Code :

```
public class SampleDownloaderActivity extends Activity implements IDownloaderClient {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LVLDownloader";
    private ProgressBar mPB;

    private TextView mStatusText;
    private TextView mProgressFraction;
    private TextView mProgressPercent;
    private TextView mAverageSpeed;
    private TextView mTimeRemaining;

    private View mDashboard;
    private View mCellMessage;

    private Button mPauseButton;
    private Button mWiFiSettingsButton;

    private boolean mStatePaused;
    private int mState;

    private IDownloaderService mRemoteService;

    private IStub mDownloaderClientStub;

    private void setState(int newState) {
        if (mState != newState) {
            mState = newState;
            mStatusText.setText(Helpers.getDownloaderStringResourceIDFromState(newState));
        }
    }

    private void setButtonPausedState(boolean paused) {
        mStatePaused = paused;
        int stringResourceID = paused ? R.string.text_button_resume :
                R.string.text_button_pause;
        mPauseButton.setText(stringResourceID);
    }

    private static class XAPKFile {
        public final boolean mIsMain;
        public final int mFileVersion;
        public final long mFileSize;

        XAPKFile(boolean isMain, int fileVersion, long fileSize) {
            mIsMain = isMain;
            mFileVersion = fileVersion;
            mFileSize = fileSize;
        }
    }


    private static final XAPKFile[] xAPKS = {
            new XAPKFile(
                    true, // true signifies a main file
                    1, // the version of the APK that the file was uploaded
                    // against
                    40257 // the length of the file in bytes
            ),
            new XAPKFile(
                    false, // false signifies a patch file
                    1, // the version of the APK that the patch file was uploaded
                    // against
                    0L // the length of the patch file in bytes
            )
    };

    boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
        for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
            String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);
            if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    void validateXAPKZipFiles() {
        AsyncTask<Object, DownloadProgressInfo, Boolean> validationTask = new AsyncTask<Object, DownloadProgressInfo, Boolean>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mDashboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCellMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mStatusText.setText(R.string.text_verifying_download);
                mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mCancelValidation = true;
                    }
                });
                mPauseButton.setText(R.string.text_button_cancel_verify);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
                for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
                    String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(
                            SampleDownloaderActivity.this,
                            xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);
                    if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(SampleDownloaderActivity.this, fileName,
                            xf.mFileSize, false))
                        return false;
                    fileName = Helpers
                            .generateSaveFileName(SampleDownloaderActivity.this, fileName);
                    ZipResourceFile zrf;
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 256];
                    try {
                        zrf = new ZipResourceFile(fileName);
                        ZipEntryRO[] entries = zrf.getAllEntries();
                        /**
                         * First calculate the total compressed length
                         */
                        long totalCompressedLength = 0;
                        for (ZipEntryRO entry : entries) {
                            totalCompressedLength += entry.mCompressedLength;
                        }
                        float averageVerifySpeed = 0;
                        long totalBytesRemaining = totalCompressedLength;
                        long timeRemaining;
                        /**
                         * Then calculate a CRC for every file in the Zip file,
                         * comparing it to what is stored in the Zip directory.
                         * Note that for compressed Zip files we must extract
                         * the contents to do this comparison.
                         */
                        for (ZipEntryRO entry : entries) {
                            if (-1 != entry.mCRC32) {
                                long length = entry.mUncompressedLength;
                                CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
                                DataInputStream dis = null;
                                try {
                                    dis = new DataInputStream(
                                            zrf.getInputStream(entry.mFileName));

                                    long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                                    while (length > 0) {
                                        int seek = (int) (length > buf.length ? buf.length
                                                : length);
                                        dis.readFully(buf, 0, seek);
                                        crc.update(buf, 0, seek);
                                        length -= seek;
                                        long currentTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                                        long timePassed = currentTime - startTime;
                                        if (timePassed > 0) {
                                            float currentSpeedSample = (float) seek
                                                    / (float) timePassed;
                                            if (0 != averageVerifySpeed) {
                                                averageVerifySpeed = SMOOTHING_FACTOR
                                                        * currentSpeedSample
                                                        + (1 - SMOOTHING_FACTOR)
                                                        * averageVerifySpeed;
                                            } else {
                                                averageVerifySpeed = currentSpeedSample;
                                            }
                                            totalBytesRemaining -= seek;
                                            timeRemaining = (long) (totalBytesRemaining / averageVerifySpeed);
                                            this.publishProgress(
                                                    new DownloadProgressInfo(
                                                            totalCompressedLength,
                                                            totalCompressedLength
                                                                    - totalBytesRemaining,
                                                            timeRemaining,
                                                            averageVerifySpeed)
                                            );
                                        }
                                        startTime = currentTime;
                                        if (mCancelValidation)
                                            return true;
                                    }
                                    if (crc.getValue() != entry.mCRC32) {
                                        Log.e(Constants.TAG,
                                                "CRC does not match for entry: "
                                                        + entry.mFileName);
                                        Log.e(Constants.TAG,
                                                "In file: " + entry.getZipFileName());
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                } finally {
                                    if (null != dis) {
                                        dis.close();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(DownloadProgressInfo... values) {
                onDownloadProgress(values[0]);
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                if (result) {
                    mDashboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mCellMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mStatusText.setText(R.string.text_validation_complete);
                    mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    mPauseButton.setText(android.R.string.ok);
                } else {
                    mDashboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mCellMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mStatusText.setText(R.string.text_validation_failed);
                    mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    mPauseButton.setText(android.R.string.cancel);
                }
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        };
        validationTask.execute(new Object());
    }

    /**
     * If the download isn't present, we initialize the download UI. This ties
     * all of the controls into the remote service calls.
     */
    private void initializeDownloadUI() {
        mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub
                (this, SampleDownloaderService.class);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mStatusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        mProgressFraction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAsFraction);
        mProgressPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAsPercentage);
        mAverageSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAverageSpeed);
        mTimeRemaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTimeRemaining);
        mDashboard = findViewById(R.id.downloaderDashboard);
        mCellMessage = findViewById(R.id.approveCellular);
        mPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        mWiFiSettingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wifiSettingsButton);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mStatePaused) {
                    mRemoteService.requestContinueDownload();
                } else {
                    mRemoteService.requestPauseDownload();
                }
                setButtonPausedState(!mStatePaused);
            }
        });

        mWiFiSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }
        });

        Button resumeOnCell = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resumeOverCellular);
        resumeOnCell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mRemoteService.setDownloadFlags(IDownloaderService.FLAGS_DOWNLOAD_OVER_CELLULAR);
                mRemoteService.requestContinueDownload();
                mCellMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        final OnObbStateChangeListener mEventListener = new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
                Log.d("", "path=" + path + "; state=" + state);
                if (state == OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED) {
                    Log.d("", "OPEN");
                } else {
                    Log.d("", "ERROR");
                }
            }
        };

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String packageName = getPackageName();
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File expPath = new File(root.toString() + "/Android/obb/" + packageName);

                try {
                   /* if (expPath.exists()) {
                        String strMainPath = expPath + File.separator + "main." + getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode + "." + packageName + ".obb";
                        File f = new File(strMainPath);
                        if (f.exists()) {
                            Log.e("Path ", "=====>Exists");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Path ", "=====> Not Exists");
                        }
                        ZipResourceFile zip = new ZipResourceFile(strMainPath);
                        InputStream iStream = zip.getInputStream("stage1_popup");
                        BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        option.inPurgeable = true;

                        File imageFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/mintshowapp/com/fileexpansionexample/main/3/mintshowapp/com/fileexpansionexample/obb/stage1_popup.gif");
                        if(imageFile.exists()){
                            String path=imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }

                        Glide.with(SampleDownloaderActivity.this).load(imageFile).into(image);
                    }*/

                    StorageManager mSM = (StorageManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
                    File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    String mObbPath = new File(file, "main.1.app.com.expanson.obb").getPath();

                    /*if (mObbPath != null && mObbPath.startsWith("/")) {
                        mObbPath = mObbPath.substring(1);
                    }*/

                    if (mSM.mountObb(mObbPath, null, mEventListener)) {
                        Log.d("", "MAIN");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("", "ERROR");
                    }
                    String path = mSM.getMountedObbPath(mObbPath);

                    System.out.print(path);
                    Glide.with(SampleDownloaderActivity.this).load(path + "/stage1_popup.gif").into(image);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        initializeDownloadUI();


        if (!expansionFilesDelivered()) {

            try {
                Intent launchIntent = SampleDownloaderActivity.this
                        .getIntent();
                Intent intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification = new Intent(
                        SampleDownloaderActivity
                                .this, SampleDownloaderActivity.this.getClass());
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setAction(launchIntent.getAction());

                if (launchIntent.getCategories() != null) {
                    for (String category : launchIntent.getCategories()) {
                        intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.addCategory(category);
                    }
                }

                // Build PendingIntent used to open this activity from
                // Notification
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        SampleDownloaderActivity.this,
                        0, intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                // Request to start the download
                int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this,
                        pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);

                if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {
                    // The DownloaderService has started downloading the files,
                    // show progress
                    initializeDownloadUI();
                    return;
                } // otherwise, download not needed so we fall through to
                // starting the movie
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot find own package! MAYDAY!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            validateXAPKZipFiles();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Connect the stub to our service on start.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        if (null != mDownloaderClientStub) {
            mDownloaderClientStub.connect(this);
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect the stub from our service on stop
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (null != mDownloaderClientStub) {
            mDownloaderClientStub.disconnect(this);
        }
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(Messenger m) {
        mRemoteService = DownloaderServiceMarshaller.CreateProxy(m);
        mRemoteService.onClientUpdated(mDownloaderClientStub.getMessenger());
    }


    @Override
    public void onDownloadStateChanged(int newState) {
        setState(newState);
        boolean showDashboard = true;
        boolean showCellMessage = false;
        boolean paused;
        boolean indeterminate;
        switch (newState) {
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_IDLE:
                // STATE_IDLE means the service is listening, so it's
                // safe to start making calls via mRemoteService.
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = true;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_CONNECTING:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FETCHING_URL:
                showDashboard = true;
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = true;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_DOWNLOADING:
                paused = false;
                showDashboard = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;

            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_CANCELED:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_UNLICENSED:
                paused = true;
                showDashboard = false;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_NEED_CELLULAR_PERMISSION:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_WIFI_DISABLED_NEED_CELLULAR_PERMISSION:
                showDashboard = false;
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                showCellMessage = true;
                break;

            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_BY_REQUEST:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_ROAMING:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_SDCARD_UNAVAILABLE:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_COMPLETED:
                showDashboard = false;
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = false;
                validateXAPKZipFiles();
                return;
            default:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = true;
                showDashboard = true;
        }
        int newDashboardVisibility = showDashboard ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
        if (mDashboard.getVisibility() != newDashboardVisibility) {
            mDashboard.setVisibility(newDashboardVisibility);
        }
        int cellMessageVisibility = showCellMessage ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
        if (mCellMessage.getVisibility() != cellMessageVisibility) {
            mCellMessage.setVisibility(cellMessageVisibility);
        }

        mPB.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
        setButtonPausedState(paused);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the state of the various controls based on the progressinfo object
     * sent from the downloader service.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDownloadProgress(DownloadProgressInfo progress) {
        mAverageSpeed.setText(getString(R.string.kilobytes_per_second,
                Helpers.getSpeedString(progress.mCurrentSpeed)));
        mTimeRemaining.setText(getString(R.string.time_remaining,
                Helpers.getTimeRemaining(progress.mTimeRemaining)));

        progress.mOverallTotal = progress.mOverallTotal;
        mPB.setMax((int) (progress.mOverallTotal >> 8));
        mPB.setProgress((int) (progress.mOverallProgress >> 8));
        mProgressPercent.setText(Long.toString(progress.mOverallProgress
                * 100 /
                progress.mOverallTotal) + "%");
        mProgressFraction.setText(Helpers.getDownloadProgressString
                (progress.mOverallProgress,
                        progress.mOverallTotal));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        this.mCancelValidation = true;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}

LOG:

 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
10-01 11:32:04.453 12394-12414/app.com.expanson I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=69KB
10-01 11:32:04.454 12394-12414/app.com.expanson I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=62KB
10-01 11:32:04.611 12394-12473/app.com.expanson I/RequestAddCookies: Cookie store not available in HTTP context
10-01 11:32:04.702 12394-12473/app.com.expanson I/ResponseProcessCookies: Cookie store not available in HTTP context
10-01 11:32:04.877 12394-12414/app.com.expanson I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=125KB, data=66KB
    After code cache collection, code=125KB, data=66KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
10-01 11:32:04.936 12394-12473/app.com.expanson I/RequestAddCookies: Cookie store not available in HTTP context
10-01 11:32:04.964 12394-12473/app.com.expanson I/ResponseProcessCookies: Cookie store not available in HTTP context
10-01 11:32:05.177 12394-12473/app.com.expanson D/CancellableIntentService: stopSelf
10-01 11:32:05.179 12394-12473/app.com.expanson D/CancellableIntentService: afterStopSelf
10-01 11:32:05.209 12394-12394/app.com.expanson D/CancellableIntentService: onDestroy
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the internet on Emulator. I have a problem because internet d'not worked on my emulator. For more information how to enable internet:

[Android emulator not able to access the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet)

Comment: I was using real device and there was active internet connection on device.

Comment: Are you try build reales version and testing ?@LovekushVishwakarma

Comment: :( , I hope you can fix it. When I have time I look more detailed. To me help this link : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config/#0