# react native Fetch Network request failed on android

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to receive some simple json from mocky.

React native fetch function:

```
getMemberDomainList = async (name) => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://5c9cc9ed3be4e30014a7d287.mockapi.io/api/domain', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

I have tested the address in chrome on windows, it returns the expected mock data. But when the function is called on my android phone I get this error
[image]

Error from remote debugger

```
...\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2348 TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (...\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4337)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (...\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10760)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (...\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10511)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (...\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10343)
    at ...\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10449
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (...\Libraries\Components\DrawerAndroid\DrawerLayoutAndroid.android.js:11)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (...\Libraries\ART\ReactNativeART.js:362)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/79251787-d190-4650-8040-23d091c08738:2334
    at MessageQueue.__guard (...\Libraries\ART\ReactNativeART.js:312)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (...\Libraries\ART\ReactNativeART.js:139)
```

I'm also running a WebView in my app, which is pointing to a web url, it loads perfectly so I am sure that the phone has internet permission and access etc.

Comment: it could be because of `http` ... `https` is needed

Comment: in your remote debugger ... what  did this `console.error(error); print ?
  `

Comment: remote debugger not workin unfortunately. But good point on the https, will try another mock service and see if that resolves it

Comment: switching to a https mock api seemed to make a difference, at least the stack trace looks a bit different. Same error though "network request failed"

Comment: Have you tried to exec the same api request using `axios` ?

Comment: Hey! No. Though I have found out that the mockapi.io also doesn't work as expected in postman, only got it working in my browser. So I think the problem is the api service - Just tried with jsonplaceholder and that worked without any errors.

Comment: Great ... glad it works!

Comment: I have the same problem. With fetch and also with axios...
For me the problem seems to be definitely inside the app.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest android versions http requests are not allowed by default. Take a look at this post for further information about allowing http request: [How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Answer (score 1):

Can't get mockapi.io to work. But the error is not persistent when using services such as:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

Might not be an android or react native related problem after all. Also had issues with mockapi.io in postman, though it works fine in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emulator then check  whether internet is working or not in this emulation using browser. If not check this: [Android emulator not able to access the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet)

I have also face this problem in emulator but when I generate a release app and install in a real device(andoid 9) then it works fine.

Comment: Yes dev/prod build can have effect on things such as internet access or which protocols are allowed. In my case I was able to fetch against https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com just fine ruling out the idea that I wasn't able to connect to the internet on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Please check backend response status.

If backend is sending contents using 205 status - `205 RESET CONTENT`

Android system recognize it as an error - `HTTP 205 had non-zero Content-Length: 25`.

You can check the status code on postman.
So, in this case, the error should be fixed on backend.
It should send contents with 200 status code.