# Angular Firestore *ngFor not showing on Android devices

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

Everything works as intended on web and ios but on an Android emulator these buttons do not display at all. Note that these buttons are dynamically created.

```
<button ion-button  (click)="function()" class="some-class" 
routerLink="/generic-routing" routerDirection="root" *ngFor="let food of 
foods | async" >
      <ion-label>
      {{food.data.FruitName}}<br>
      Temperature:<br>
      {{food.data.Temperature}}
      </ion-label>
</button>
```

anyone have any idea why this is happening on Android?

SOLVED: [Android emulator not able to access the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet)

Comment: What ionic version are you using

Comment: any chance the foods source data is not being populated on the android emulator ? You can try displaying it on the view with {{foods | async }} just to see if it renders first ...

Comment: My Ionic CLI is 5.4.15.

trying {{foods | async}} didn't work.

Looking deeper into this I think because i am on my, my android emulator can't connect to the internet.