# "Network request failed" with react-native (even with `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`)

Tags: android, react-native

I did `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` to create a new project (I'm following the official [get-started tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). When I simply run `npx react-native start` and then `npx react-native run-android` without tweaking anything everything works fine. But I need to make an API call, so I tried copying and pasting the example from the official [network tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) (only without the try/catch, so I can see the errors) into App.js (right after the imports):

```
async function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
    let response = await fetch(
        'https://reactnative.dev/movies.json'
    );
    let json = await response.json();
    console.log(json.movies);
    return json.movies;
}
```

Then right below it I added a call to that function:

```
getMoviesFromApiAsync();
```

That gives me a `Network request failed` error. This is the full error message I see on Terminal:

```
Fri May 08 2020 10:23:00.325]  WARN     Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Network request failed
onerror@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:28005:31
dispatchEvent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:34133:31
setReadyState@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:33217:33
__didCompleteResponse@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:33044:29
emit@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:3420:42
__callFunction@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2748:49
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2470:31
__guard@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2702:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2469:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

I googled around and ended up trying the following:

1) I added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to AndroidManifest.xml

2) I added a bunch of permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

3) I added `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to AndroidManifest.xml

4) I tried setting a proxy (10.0.2.2) and port (8081), as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217370/2453555)

5) I tried deleting the app from the emulator and reinstalling it, as well as clearing the cache (`npx react-native start --reset-cache`)

Nothing seems to work. I still get the same "Network request failed" message.

I'm using React Native 0.62.2 on a Pixel 2 API 28 emulator running Android 9.0, on macOS Catalina.

Comment: use try-catch for `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection`.

Comment: But what do I put inside `catch`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm stupid. I've been at this for three full days and only now I realized that the problem is that the emulator didn't have access to the internet (even after adding `android.permission.INTERNET` to the manifest). The solution was to change the DNS address of my network, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49332186/2453555).