# Android studio emulator no internet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

It was working fine and suddenly it started showing me "connected no internet"
I haven't made any changes to my router. Same laptop.

This is what I tried so far:

-Wide data

-Cold boot

-Restart Android studio

-Check for updates

-Restart/Shutdown laptop

-Delete emulator and adding a new one

-Adding new emulator with a higher API

-Changing laptop wifi DNS to `8.8.8.8`

-`adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

-Deleting `.android` folder from `C:\Users\USERNAME\`

-Emulator extended controls -> settings -> proxy -> Manual proxy configurations + hostname

The only working solution was this command:

`c:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\android\sdk\emulator\emulator -avd AVD_NAME -dns-server 8.8.8.8`

But I have to open the emulator always using this command and the CMD window must stay open. If I close it or killed the command with `ctrl+c`, internet connection is lost again.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?

I'm using Pixel 2 API 29 Android Studio 4.0.1

Thanks

EDIT:
I have looked at several SO with similar problem, nothing solved it so far.
I am still using the above command to open the emulator and force it to use 8.8.8.8 so it can have a connection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android emulator not able to access the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736038/android-emulator-not-able-to-access-the-internet)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have tried it but nothing seemed to solve it for me. I've edited my question

Comment: @ybloodz Have you already solved your issue? I'm facing the same problem, tried almost everything you did and nothing helped. I guess it has something to do with the newest Emulator update? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is turn on the `Mobile data` on it. It might be currently set as off.

Comment: WiFI and mobile data are both on. Sorry if I didn't mention that